# Can't search in site collection in sharepoint 2013

Tags: search

I've created a Search Center site collection at mycompany.net/intranet (Enterprise Search template) and it worked just fine.[image]

I've config to search in mycompany.net site collection, and it work OK.
[image]

when I go to setting, and choose Search Setting and specify http://mycompany.net/intranet in Search Center URL. Then I go back to mycompany.net and select search for everything,people or conversation, Instead of display the result, this page display like this.(If I choose This site, it work ok).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you go to "Search settings" under site collection administrator features?

Comment: yes, i'm sure that

Comment: And you are sure that you have configured it correctly? At the search center Url, did you type the adress to your search site collection followed by "/pages" ?

Comment: my root site is http://mycompany.net and my search site collection is http://mycompany.net/intranet . And I type "http://mycompany.net"/intranet in search center Url.

Comment: Are you using managed paths? What is the internal url for the search site collection? (sites/search)?

Comment: Type "mycompany.net/intranet/pages" in the search center url under search settings and wait a couple of minutes. Then it should work.

Comment: in managed path. Im create explicit inclusion for "intranet" and my internal url for search site collection is "mycompany.net/intranet" . that's all

Comment: OK. I'll try :)

Comment: thanks you so much :). It's work OK. So there is another issue that I've got, So nice of u if u have a look at this : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116334/issue-with-people-search-in-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you type correct URLs in the search settings. The search center url must be followed by `/pages` so an example would be `http://server/sites/search/pages`.

The same goes out to the setting to send a users query to a custom result page. Then `/pages/results.aspx"` must be added to the rest of the URL, like this example: `http://server/sites/search/pages/results.aspx`

In your scenario it would be `http://mycompany.net/intranet/pages` and `http://mycompany.net/intranet/pages/results.aspx`.

Comment: Thanks you. I've figure it out. So can you have a look at another question at : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116334/issue-with-people-search-in-sharepoint-2013