# Issue with people search in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: people-search

I've implement people search in Search Center site collection. But I got problem when I try to view people profile.I've got . Sorry, something went wrong. user not found. Can anyone help me:)

Comment: The problem I have look exactly like this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97882/my-sites-link-in-search-resuls-is-incorrect-escaped . There is an answer for this but I didn't understand it. Can anyone show my step by step to do it. I'm new to SP 2013